# Doxygen enum with explicit hard value

Tags: doxygen

I have a C enum with around 50 values (they are error codes). Besides the first value, the numbering is kept automatic.

```
typedef enum {
    MY_STATUS_OK = 0,
    MY_STATUS_ERROR_UNKNOWN,
    MY_STATUS_ERROR_A,
    MY_STATUS_ERROR_B,
    /* ... */
    MY_STATUS_ERROR_LAST
} my_status_t;
```

I do get an enum description in the HTML, but it doesn't show the explicit value, only the enum values' name.

I want to document the association between hard value and enum value name. Right now when I get an error value, I need to manually count the index in the enum to find out what it means.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Which settings in your doxygen configuration file different from the standard doxygen configuration file? I don't think the requested functionality is available in doxygen (haven't seen it with a compiler either), probably best to file an enhancement request (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new).

Comment: old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929925/is-there-a-way-to-get-doxygen-to-show-enum-numerical-values-without-changing-css