# Documenting enum class values with doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

in my project I use enum class a lot and I'm using doxygen as documentation system.
I find very difficult to produce documentation of enum classes when multiple enum classes are declared in the same file and they have the same members. 
For example, the following code is not generating the correct documentation for enum class IMAGE_REPORTING in final HTML output:

```
namespace mapper
{
  /* CONNECTION RELATED */
  /** @enum mapper::SECURE_WEBSOCKET
   *  \author Michele Adduci
   *  \ingroup Core
   *  @brief is a strongly typed enum class representing the status of websocket connection
   *  @var mapper::SECURE_WEBSOCKET::DISABLED
   *  is coded as std::int8_t of value 0
   *  @var mapper::SECURE_WEBSOCKET::ENABLED
   *  is coded as std::int8_t of value 1
   */
  enum class SECURE_WEBSOCKET : std::int8_t {DISABLED = 0, ENABLED = 1};

  /* IMAGE RELATED */
  /** @enum mapper::IMAGE_REPORTING
   *  \author Michele Adduci
   *  \ingroup Core
   *  @brief is a strongly typed enum class representing the status of image reporting
   *  @var mapper::IMAGE_REPORTING::DISABLED
   *  is coded as std::int8_t of value 0
   *  @var mapper::IMAGE_REPORTING::ENABLED
   *  is coded as std::int8_t of value 1
 */
  enum class IMAGE_REPORTING : std::int8_t {DISABLED = 0, ENABLED = 1};
}
```

Output: 
[image: Doxygen output]

Any idea of what is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use inline documentation, which works for me:

```
/** @enum mapper::IMAGE_REPORTING
 *  \author Michele Adduci
 *  \ingroup Core
 *  @brief is a strongly typed enum class representing the status of image reporting
 */
enum class IMAGE_REPORTING : std::int8_t {
  DISABLED = 0, /**< is coded as std::int8_t of value 0 */
  ENABLED = 1   /**< is coded as std::int8_t of value 1 */
}
```

and similar for the other.

Comment: Note you can also remove the @enum command in the example above, it is redundant is only a source of typing errors.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue with global enums. Some header files generated a link for enums and other header files did not. You must explicitly document the file.

Here is a excerpt from this page int the documentation.
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#memberdoc

> To document a global C function, typedef, enum or preprocessor
>   definition you must first document the file that contains it (usually
>   this will be a header file, because that file contains the information
>   that is exported to other source files).
>
> Attention
>       Let's repeat that, because it is often overlooked: to document global objects (functions, typedefs, enum, macros, etc), you must
>   document the file in which they are defined. In other words, there
>   must at least be a
>
> ```
> /*! \file */ 
>
> or a
>
> /** @file */ 
>
> line in this file.
> ```

Comment: mmm...it sounds like a new addition..back in 2014 it wasn't there, but thanks for reporting it